# Finding a distribution that fits different observations of data

Tags: distributions, goodness-of-fit, fitting, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I am observing session lengths on a network. I want to fit a distribution to the data that I have collected. I have data from two different observations (about a month apart). The plot below shows CCDFs of both observations. As can be seen, the curves look pretty similar in shape. I was able to fit the Pareto distribution (after doing some research) to both curves. However, both fits have different parameters. I am unsure how to come up with a general distribution that is a good approximation to both individual fits.

I have tried to average out the parameters, generate the CCDF for a Pareto distribution with the new parameter and then perform KS-test using the new theoretical CCDF and the observations. However, I have not been able to achieve fruitful results.

Is there a way in which I can find a general fit for these individual curves and then perform a test (e.g., the KS-test) that will validate the result?

The purpose of this exercise is to come up with a mathematical model for the session lengths on the network. I want to have a single model that is applicable to session lengths over different periods (within some bounds).

[image]

Comment: Why would you assume the parameters are the same?  Looking at the plots I would assume the parameters had changed over time, and just go with that.

Comment: The purpose of this exercise is to come up with a mathematical model for the session lengths on the network. I want to have a single model that is applicable to session lengths over different periods (within some bounds).